# How to prevent nodes from creating only small blocks to earn fee?

Tags: block

I read [What are the minimum sizes for transactions and blocks in Bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/54679) that there is no min limit - just a max limit of 128MB - for a block.

For example if a miner always takes a single transaction and creates a block from it, he probably will be faster as most other nodes and will gain most taxes or not?

Answer (score 0):

> I read on SO that there is no min limit - just a max limit of 128MB - for a block.

Bitcoin blocks have a max weight unit of 4MB, not 128 MB. Blocks that large (128MB) would lead to extreme network centralization due to a need for high-end hardware to run a validating node... but anyways.

> For example if a miner always takes a single transaction and creates a block from it, he probably will be faster as most other nodes and will gain most taxes or not?

No, the number of transactions in a block has no bearing on how fast the block is mined. Putting more transactions in a block does mean that the merkle root computation will take a little bit longer, but this calculation is done in parallel by the miner's bitcoin node, not by the mining hardware itself. So a miner does not have any advantage/disadvantage in mining a large/small block.

Comment: I put the link in the question, is it wrong or do i not understand it correctly?

Comment: The question you linked is correct, but I don't see how it conflicts with what I wrote?

Comment: oh ok, then i probably have another problem. Thank you

Comment: There isn't a direct advantage in mining a larger block, but the miner will generally collect more fees if they include more transactions. So miners are generally incentivized to make larger blocks, rather than smaller.